# Why did the artist do that?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-artist-and-the-model

At the end of the Artist and the Model the artist shoots himself. The war is ending, he's just finished his masterpiece and is having a book written about his life. Why would he kill himself?

I have my own theories but would really like them confirmed.